# Why do complete ANOVA tables matter?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, estimation, interpretation, tables

I'm trained as a mathematical statistician; my degree is technically "mathematics" but I study statistics. So let's consider classical, one-way ANOVA. Textbooks will teach that to perform ANOVA you need to construct a table that includes error sum-of-squares, total sum-of-squares, and a treatment sum-of-squares. Put these into a table, compute degrees of freedom, compute a test statistic via ratios of sums of squares, compute p-value, and you're done. Many books seem to emphasize the importance of including the sums of squares and their decomposition and the importance of the decomposition itself; in other words, authors seem to think the entire table is important, such as Box in *Statistics for Experimenters* where he says software should report an entire table.

I do understand the mathematical details of these tables. What I don't understand fully is why anyone cares about the table itself.

Yes, I get the importance of general diagnostics and diagnostic plots; to me, ANOVA is just linear regression. I could imagine reformulating the regression model to express ANOVA in different forms (I like estimating contrasts directly, for example). I think pair-wise confidence intervals such as Tukey's intervals are very important in making conclusions about the data.

What I don't get is why people care so much about computing this decomposition of the total sum of squares beyond simply computing a test statistic. After you get a test statistic/p-value and do the hypothesis test, why do these sums of squares matter? I suppose the error sum-of-squares can be used to estimate the standard error of the residuals, but why does the treatment sum of squares matter? I'm not sure what useful quantity it would be estimating. Sorry for rambling, but hopefully I've made clear what I'm not fully grasping.

Comment: In time-honored jargon, the F-test is testing variability among groups with variability within groups, Among other things the ANOVA table (one-factor) displays this info, and I feel my job is not complete until I have had a chance to look at it.

Comment: Some of this might be history, anova was historically **not** just linear regression, that is a later viewpoint. You might ask about the history of anova ...